# erasing a pointer to an element in a static vector, in the element's own destructor

Tags: c++, visual-c++, pointers, destructor, stdvector

The code below is from a game I've written with dynamic memory management. I have a static vector called 'all_gadgets' containing a pointer to every gadget in the game.
When a gadget is deleted in runtime, I want to remove the corresponding pointer from the static vector. I've tried this:

```
Gadget::~Gadget(){
    int i = Gadget::all_gadgets.size();
    for (std::vector<Gadget *>::iterator it = Gadget::all_gadgets.begin(); it!=all_gadgets.end(); ++it){

        if ((*it)==this){
            Gadget::all_gadgets.erase(it);

            break;
        }
    }


    int j = (i - Gadget::all_gadgets.size());
    if(j!=1)
        std::cout << j << " ooops! Gadget not deleted!!" << std::endl;
}
```

In the code above, j will turn out to be zero :( Any suggestions why?

Setting the pointer to null is not an option. 
I'm using VC10.

Comment: How about putting a cout inside the if? That way you can confirm whether or not it actually reaches inside. Also, are you certain that this Gadget is actually inside the all_gadgets list? Have you tried printing all_gadgets.size()?

Comment: Can multiple threads access the `vector`? What is the value of `j`?

Comment: And add a `cout` at the point where you insert the gadget into the vector. Maybe that failed.

Comment: @hmjd: The question clearly says that "`j` will turn out to be zero".

Comment: I use the vector for saving and loading from file. as long as nothing is deleted it works fine: pointers are inserted in the vector and I can access the actual objects through them

Answer (score 2):

Use an invasive double linked-list for this, it will be more efficient for insertion, removal, and in-order iteration.

Normally, linked-lists suffer from poor locality.  But with your vector of pointers, while the pointers themselves may be stored with great locality, the content requires an extra level of indirection, and loss of locality.

With an invasive linked list, the locality is exactly as good as the locality of the content.  So you achieve the theoretical upper bound for locality, plus cheap insertion and removal.

---

Your actual problem probably arises from not doing the insertion for every single constructor.  The compiler generates a copy constructor (and in C++11, move constructor) by default, which would not update your `all_gadgets` list, unless you provide your own.

Comment: the thing is, the prog does enter the if-statement.

Comment: @Nolf: Does it enter the if statement on the same object where `j` comes out zero?  Or are some objects successfully removed, and some not (depending on what constructor was used)?

Comment: it's on the same object and the problem is the same for all objects.  I'm sure the problem is not with the constructor cause I use the same vector to load/save from file and then all objects are succesfully saved.